# Laravel query orderBy has 'media' using Spatie\MediaLibrary

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

Im currently using the `Spatie\MediaLibrary` for my reviews model.

I got a query getting all reviews but im trying to show reviews that has images first using `orderBy`.

`app\Models\Product.php` **Not working**

```
public function reviews(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class)->orderBy('media');
}
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'media' in 'order clause'

Using `has` 'media' or `doesnthave` 'media' works. But I would like in the 1 query.

```
public function activeImageReviews(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class)->has('media');
```

Comment: @francisco - Are you able to provide a example as I cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists a column called 'media' in the database you mig try:

```
public function reviews(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
{
  return $this->hasMany(Review::class)->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN `media` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown column 'media'` implies that the column is not created in the table, make sure your migration is properly created.

In other case, if your `media` is from a normalized, then your approach is supposed to be creating the relation between your **Review model** and your **Media model** then making the relation using `with()`

```
return $this->hasMany(Review::class)->with('media')->orderBy('media.column');
```

---

Edit:

Since it is File-based only, then it is recommended to sort the collection after fetching as by documentation:

```
                    // sortBy
$sorted = $collection->sortByDesc(function(Model $item) {
    $media = ...;
    return $item->has($media);
});
```

Comment: Using the Spatie\MediaLibrary. There is a media table in the db that hosts all the models images. 

->has('media') and 
->doesnthave('media')

Comment: @TonySawlwin In this case, you have one of two options: 1. To sort the data after fetching it in collection using `has('media')`. 2. Check the documentation of `Spatie\MediaLibrary` of its migration and integrate it with the model relation.